# Match Whole Array in Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a simple mongodb collection (an extract of aggregation pipeline),  say

```
[
 {_id : [3, 3] ,  val : 7},
 {_id : [3, 2] ,  val : 9},
 {_id : [1, 3] ,  val: 10}
]
```

I want to do a `$match` to get the `[3, 3]` record only. 
However using

```
$match : {$_id: { $all: [3, 3]}}
```

returns `[3, 2]` as well, which is what we don't want. Any takers?

Comment: Yup. Complete lie, as `_id` cannot be an array.

Comment: i think you missed the part of my question saying that its an extract of aggregation pipe line, i can be an array thus

Comment: I think you missed the part of your question to show your workings and proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only see this possibly occurring under a condition like this:

```js
{ "like": 1, "id": 3, "val": 7 },
{ "like": 1, "id": 3, "val": 7 },
{ "like": 2, "id": 3, "val": 5 },
{ "like": 2, "id": 2, "val": 5 },
```

And then in aggregate:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$like",
        "id": { "$push": "$id" },
        "val": { "$max": "$val" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$id",
        "val": 1
    }}
])
```

Which gives:

```js
{ "_id" : [ 3, 2 ], "val" : 5 }
{ "_id" : [ 3, 3 ], "val" : 7 }
```

For which we come down to, the `$all` condition is basically considered as a "set" just as `$in` is. And that means `[3,3]` is basically reduced to `3`. Therefore if you want an "explicit" match then please do so:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$like",
        "id": { "$push": "$id" },
        "val": { "$max": "$val" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$id",
        "val": 1
    }},
    { "$match": {
        "_id": [3,3]
    }}
])
```